# Firebase Creating Dynamic Links with the REST API call using Javascript giving 400

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to create Firebase Dynamic Links with REST API using simple Javascript ajax code, but every time I am getting 400 bad request, though I have tried and implemented the documentation described at https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links. I couldn't find any solution for this.

Whats wrong I am doing here please help.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Change Content

```
    <script>
  function loadDoc() {
    var params = {
      longDynamicLink:
        "https://thepary.page.link/?link=http://www.example.com/&apn=com.example.android&ibi=com.example.ios",
      dynamicLinkInfo: {
        domainUriPrefix: "https://thepary.page.link",
        link: `https://threads-1511.web.app/threads/`,
        iosInfo: {
          iosBundleId: "com.bundleId",
          iosAppStoreId: "1512677811",
          iosIpadBundleId: "com.bundleId",
        },
        androidInfo: {
          androidPackageName: "com.bundleId",
        },
        socialMetaTagInfo: {
          socialTitle: `A thread by s`,
          socialDescription: `s`,
          socialImageLink:
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/threads-1511.appspot.com/o/playstore.png?alt=media&token=896f4fe6-2882-442e-b15c-3767d61b8a70",
        },
      },
      suffix: {
        option: "SHORT",
      },
    };

    $.ajax({
      url:
        "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=[APIKEY]",
      type: "POST",
      data: params,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (response) {
        alert(response.status);
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("error");
      },
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since API expects `contentType: "application/json"`,
You need to `data: JSON.stringify(params)`